# Building Eclipse from scratch - it takes an eternity

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, junit, build

Lately I have challenged myself to build the Eclipse IDE from the source code. This will open an opportunity to start playing around with the code, and make some changes.

I found the following tutorial to guide me through the procedure: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlatformDevelopment/article.html

Especially chapter 13 of that Tutorial is helpful. Apparently I need to have the following software installed on my (Windows) machine:

- Git
- Maven Version 3.3.1 (make sure that the bin folder where you extract Maven is added to the PATH)
- Oracle 1.8 JDK or higher

I have all this software on my desktop - so I'm ready to go. I start by cloning the newest Eclipse repository and it's submodules via Git to some folder on my machine:

```
git clone -b master --recursive git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git
```

This takes a couple of minutes. Maybe half an hour at most. Eureka - the folder is now pretty full with the Eclipse source code! The vogella tutorial proceeds with the actual build command. I open the command prompt in Windows and surf (cd..) to the right spot. Then I type the command:

```
    mvn clean verify
```

I first got some errors. But thanks to the StackOverflow community, they are solved now. Please refer to this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645180/building-the-eclipse-ide-from-scratch

Eclipse builds. And it builds. And it keeps building for hours. After many hours, I get the message that the build has finished. I'm amazed it took such a long time, since my computer is quite a beast:

```
> CPU: Intel Core i7-4790K CPU @4.00GHz
> RAM: 16.0GB
> System type: 64-bit OS
> Windows 10 Home
```

Anyway, after the build has finished, the JUnit testing automatically starts. I have no option to skip it. I wait for some more hours, until I really need to stop the system and go home. I close the command prompt - knowing that I interrupt the JUnit testing. But who cares :-).

I check my filesystem, and cannot find the files about which the Vogella tutorial speaks:

```
eclipse.platform.releng.tychoeclipsebuilder/sdk/target/products/*
```

Help.. was the whole build procedure done for nothing? I want to redo the build, but is there a way to skip those JUnit testings?

**EDIT**: I followed the advice of Mr. Gerold Broser and added the `-DskipTests` flag to the `mvn clean verify` command. I believe that Eclipse is now building without doing all the JUnit testing. Nevertheless, I still feel like the build takes an eternity. I'm now waiting for 4 hours. Is this normal? Are there ways to tell the maven build tool that it can use all 4 CPU cores?

**EDIT**: The Eclipse build has finally stopped. Unfortunately, it is no big success. I get a very lengthy error message. The build has failed. I've opened up another StackOverflow post to get some help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662645/building-eclipse-from-scratch-build-failure

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Maven Surefire Plugin / Skipping Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html):

> You can also skip the tests via the command line by executing the following command:
>
> ```
> mvn ... -DskipTests
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will test it tomorrow :-)

Comment: Hi Mr. @Gerold Broser, I followed your advice. It helped me, but I'm still facing an extremely long build time. Do you have more suggestions?